# MVC5 - Refresh partial view em ajaxStop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

Olá,

Dentro da minha página de layout principal(_Layout), renderizo uma partial view que é responsável por exibir mensagens que foram adicionadas pelo controlado, através da biblioteca javascript Toastr.

Código da partial view

```
@using Biblioteca.Util
@using Biblioteca.Util.Base.UI

@if (TempData.ContainsKey("Alerta"))
{
   Alerta alerta = TempData["Alerta"] as Alerta;
   @MensagemAlerta.MostrarMensagensAlerta(alerta);
}
```

Quando os métodos das minhas páginas são executados através de POST no formulário, as mensagens são exibidas corretamente, uma vez que a página é recarregada e consequentemente a partial view também.

Meu problema, é que em alguns métodos faço a chamada via AJAX, atualizando apenas uma outra partial view com o resultado da pesquisa por exemplo. Neste cenário, como a partial view de mensagens não é recarregada, ela não é exibida para o usuário. Isto ocorre apenas quando o usuário efetua um refresh na página (F5).

A minha ideia inicial é adicionar no evento "ajaxStop" um trecho que código que faça com que a partial view de mensagens seja carregada novamente, porém estou sem saber como fazer isso.

Contro novamente com a ajuda de vocês.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller**

Crie uma ação que retorna sua "View Parcial".

```
    public ActionResult Mensagens()
    {
        return PartialView("_ViewParcialMensagens");
    }
```

**Javascript**

Cria uma função que carrega dentro de uma div o conteúdo da ação acima. Eu nunca usei `ajaxStop`, colocaria no `success` ou na `error` callbacks. Mas acredito que é a mesma coisa para `ajaxStop`

```
function salvar() {
    var dados = $("#form").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("MinhaAcao", "MeuController")',
        data: { dados },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
        },
        ajaxStop: function () {
            exibirMensagens();
        }
    });
}

function exibirMensagens() {
   $("#div-mensagens").load('@Url.Action("Mensagens", "MeuControler")');
}
```